# Understanding the template mechanism of sonata / twig

Tags: templates, doctrine, twig, sonata

I am struggling with the template engine of symfony/sonata ... normally i am familiar with inheritance and object-oriented design, but i don't understand this.

My target is, to override the DoctrineORMAdminBundle:CRUD:show_orm_one_to_many.html.twig because i believe, the list for the show function in my admin class is rendered there. I need it, because i want to show my data not only in a plain list like sonata is doing it now. I only want to override this for the show function of one explicit admin in my bundle and **not in general**!

According to the sonata documentation, i am only able to override the general template "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show.html.twig" by injecting a own inherited version of them to my service

```
- [ setTemplate, [show, AcmeBundle:TestAdmin:show.html.twig]]
```

The problem is, the base template includes / involves many other templates, sometimes accessed by object functions injected in the template by php.

How can i access/override the

```
DoctrineORMAdminBundle:CRUD:show_orm_one_to_many.html.twig
```

so that mine version is used instead of vendors one? Have i to override all chaining templates?

DoctrineORMAdminBundle:CRUD:show_orm_one_to_many.html.twig extends SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig

But i dont know, how SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig comes to the SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show.html.twig. I cant find suiting code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override templates on a field by field basis instead of overriding the whole show template.

```
$showMapper->add(
    'my_field',
    null, // let the type guesser do its thing
    ['template' => 'whatever_you_need.html.twig']
);
```

It this works and you can't find it in the docs, please consider contributing a paragraph about it.

Comment: I dont know how often i tried this way and it never works ... now i tried again and all worked like magic! Thanks, you saved my day :) (conclusion: never give up, try again an again ... ^^)

But am i right, that its not as easy like this to override every used template?

Comment: If by that you mean override `DoctrineORMAdminBundle:CRUD:show_orm_one_to_many.html.twig`, I think you can achieve that with standard template overriding as described in the sf docs…